# Resolving Generic Collections using AutoFac

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I couldn't find a question talking about resolving a collection to base classes. I have the following pseudo test class which uses AutoFac to resolve handlers:

```cs
namespace Test {

    interface IEventEmitter {}

    interface IEventHandler {}

    interface IEventHandler<in T> : IEventHandler where T: IEventEmitter {}

    interface ISomeClass : IEventEmitter {}

    class SomeClass : ISomeClass
    {
        // 2 handlers should be resolved here, not one!
        public SomeClass(IEnumerable<IEventHandler> handlers) {}
    }

    class GenericEventHandler : IEventHandler {}

    class DedicatedEventHandler : IEventHandler<ISomeClass> {}

    [TestClass]
    class TestClass
    {
        [TestMethod]
        private void TestHandlers()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // registered in order to resolve handlers
            builder.RegisterType<SomeClass>().As<ISomeClass>();

            builder.RegisterType<GenericEventHandler>().As<IEventHandler>();

            builder.RegisterType<DedicatedEventHandler>().As<IEventHandler<ISomeClass>>();

            var container = builder.Build();

            using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var instanceWithHandlers = scope.Resolve<ISomeClass>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I am registering a dedicated handler to ISomeClass interface, as well as a generic
one for any type of event emitter. My expectation is that SomeClass constructor will be injected with 2 handlers- the generic and the dedicated one.

Unfortunately, that's not the case. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you register an interface with `As` Autofac does not automatically registers its base interfaces.

So you need to manually tell to Autofac that your `DedicatedEventHandler` is also an `IEventHandler` with:

```
builder.RegisterType<DedicatedEventHandler>()
       .As<IEventHandler<ISomeClass>>()
       .As<IEventHandler>();
```

If you want to register a type with all its interfaces you can use the  `AsImplementedInterfaces` method.

So the equivalent of the above registration is the following:

```
builder.RegisterType<DedicatedEventHandler>()
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: Oh btw- Since we are registering TWO interfaces here, the Dedicated appear in ANY IEventHandler collection, correct? Is there a way to perform a full match in order to restrict resolution just to SomeClass?

Comment: Yes `Dedicated` will be included anytime you request `IEnumerable<IEventHandler>`, so you cannot restrict this for only SomeClass. Autofac is not the best in contextual bindings but you can have a look at the Named registration feature or the https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Typed-Named-And-Keyed-Services or the metadata support: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Metadata

Comment: Yes, I suppose named/keyed services will work better, although I was able to find a rather ugly way to solve it.

    builder.Register(c => new SomeClass(c.Resolve<IEnumerable<IEventHandler>>()
                                     .Concat(c.Resolve<IEnumerable<IEventHandler<ISomeClass>>().Cast<IEventHandler>()))).As<ISomeClass>();